# OV2640 Camera module over I2C to NXP LPC1768 Microcontroller?

Tags: camera, sensors, i2c, lpc, nxp-microcontroller

I am new to embedded, and even newer to camera sensors - please bear with me. I am trying to interface between the OV2640 Camera module ([OV2640 Datasheet](http://www.uctronics.com/download/cam_module/OV2640DS.pdf), [module with breakout board](https://my.st.com/public/STe2ecommunities/ImageLibrary/111/111.jpg)). So I connected the following:

- OV2640  -  LPC1768
- GND ------- p1  (GND)
- VCC ------- p40 (Vout - 3.3V)
- SDA ------- p28 (I2C SDA)
- SCL ------- p27 (I2C SCL)

I am trying to get it to work through the [SCCB](http://www.ovt.com/download_document.php?type=document&DID=63), and that's why the I2C is connected. But it seems I am not able to set that right.

This is the code I have right now:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "mbed.h"

Serial pc(USBTX, USBRX); // tx, rx to the PC

I2C cam(p28, p27);      // I2C

int main() {
    pc.printf("Starting new program\r\n");
    cam.start();

    int          addressCOM7  = 0x12;
    int          addressCLKRC = 0x11;
    int          addressCOM2  = 0x09;
    const char   data         = 1;
    int          length       = 8; 
    bool         repeated     = false;
    int          rtn          = -1;

    cam.frequency(400000); 
    pc.printf("Camera I2c set to 400,000Hz \r\n");

    rtn = cam.write(addressCOM7, "1", addressCOM7 + data);
    if ( rtn == 0)pc.printf("COM7 set to 1. \r\n");
    else          pc.printf("Error Setting COM7 to 1. \r\n");
    rtn = cam.write(addressCLKRC, &data, addressCLKRC + data);
    if (rtn == 0) pc.printf("CLKRC set to 1. \r\n");
    else          pc.printf("Error Setting CLKRC to 1. \r\n");
    rtn = cam.write(addressCOM2, &data, addressCOM2 + data);
    if (rtn == 0) pc.printf("COM2 set to 1. \r\n");
    else          pc.printf("Error Setting COM2 to 1. \r\n");

    int address = 0x30;
    char readData[128];

    strcpy (readData,"");

    while(1) {
        cam.read(address, readData, 128);
        wait(2.0);
        pc.printf("1 =  '%s'\r\n", readData);       
    }
}
```

I am not able to write or read through the I2C - What am I doing wrong here?

Also, believe that XCLK needs to be tied to the OV2640 module, how can it be done from the LPC1768 microcontroller?

Comment: SCL and SDA **must** be connected to Vcc through separate resistors, probably 4.7K ohms. I2C **cannot** function without them.

Comment: I did add a 4.7kOhm resistors from both SCL and SDA to 3.3Vout (Yellow, Purple, Black, Brown, Brown). It did not change the no results.